# Rewrite to ip address - website unavailable

Tags: .htaccess

This is my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xxx\.xx\.xxx\.xx/domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Website isn't available, this is error I get:
`The page isn't redirecting properly`

How to create this redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xxx\.xx\.xxx\.xx/domain\.com [NC]
```

with this

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !xxx\.xx\.xxx\.xx
```

Comment: The `%{SERVER_ADDR}` is the local address that the listening socket is bound to which handled the request, it will still loop if a request is made for `http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx/domain.com/`

Answer (score 2):

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable does not contain any URI path elements in it, it is **only** the hostname that is given as the `Host:` request header. This is usually what appears in the hostname part of a URL:

- **`http://www.google.com/blahblahblah`** = `www.google.com`
- **`http://localhost/foo/bar/zzzzz`** = `localhost`
- **`http://123.45.67.89/something/something/`** = `123.45.67.89`

Just get rid of all of the URI from your condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xxx\.xx\.xxx\.xx$ [NC]
```